# multiple arithmetic expressions in processing

Tags: processing

Ok, so still getting use to the basics with processing, and I am unsure if this is the correct way to do multiple arithmetic expressions with the same data, should I be typing each as its own code, or doing it like this?

here is the question;

> 1. Write the statements which perform the following arithmetic operations (note: the variable names can be changed). (i)  a=50 b=60
>      c=43 result1 = a+b+c result2=a*b result3 = a/b

here is my code;

```
short a = 50;
short b = 60;
short c = 43;
int sum = a+b+c; // Subsection i
print (sum);
int sum2 = a*b; // Subsection ii
print (sum2);
int sum3 =a/b; // Subsection iii
print (sum3);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the same variable for a in all three expressions, like you're doing, is the right way.  This means that if you wanted to change a, b, or c you'd only have to change it in one place.

Comment: Great, thanks for answering.

When it comes to coding just the sum of  10/2, would i write it like this?

    double a = 10.0;
    short b = 2;
    double result;
    result = a/b;
    printIn (result);


Thanks again :)

Comment: If the a and b are coming from somewhere else, then yes.  If you know for some reason that e.g. the 2 is never going to change, then you can just write it directly (e.g. ```println(10/2)```), but in places where you're using a number multiple times it's great practice to give it it's own name.

Comment: Great thanks, so for the question
"(iv)  Write the arithmetic expression which would assign the remainder of the following divisions to individual variables.
 
10/2"

should I just write the printIn(10/2) method, or would i need to do this another way?

Comment: If you're assigning the remainder to individual variables, you're going to have to do something other than println.  You're going to have to assign it to a variable.

Comment: Great, thank you so much for your help! :D What seemed like just random letters and numbers is now all making perfect sense!  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention what language, but there are a couple problems.  It's hard to say what your knowledge level is, so I apologize in advance if this is beyond the scope of the assignment.

First, your variables are defined as `short` but they end up being assigned to `int` variables.  That's implicit typecasting.  Granted, `short` is basically a subset of `int` in most languages, but you should be aware that you're doing it and implicit typecasting can cause problems.  It's slightly bad practice.

Second, your variable names are all called `sumX` but only one is a sum.  That's definitely bad practice.  Variable names should be meaningful and represent what they actually are.

Third, your division is dividing two integers and storing the result into an integer.  This means that if you're using a strongly typed language you will be truncating the fractional portion of the quotient.  You will get `0` as your output: 50 / 60 = 0.8333[...] which when converted to an integer truncates to 0.  You may wish to consider using `double` or `float` as your data types if your answer is supposed to be accurate.

Comment: I agree with this. In processing you should use `int` instead of `short`. Also beware of combining ints or global variables such as `frameRate` or `frameCount` or methods that return ints in calculations with floats. If you end up needing more precision, such as in your last statement `int sum3 = a/b;` you might consider something like `float sum3 = float(a)/float(b);`. If you get one int in the mix, your calculations will appear to be off.